# How to build a webservice (host) that executes stored procedures in a database?

Tags: c#, web-services, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api2, owin

In our software clients can create multiple (Sybase SQL Anywhere) databases (Administrations). They all share the exact same schema and have all the same database objects, for example stored procedures.

Many of our customers have asked to write directly into these databases (to write their own custom software), but we have a closed database (thus users don't have direct data access) policy to prevent corrupt data entry.

As a workaround, I thought about writing a webservice host. Via this host, I would like to execute stored procedures.
I was thinking of using WCF services as this gives me a nice WSDL-definition, but my company rather sees me using the same concepts as other projects in our company (due to standardization), so it should use WebAPI and/or Owin.

To explain where I want to go, here's some info:
I have two identical databases, CorpDb and SchoolDb. Both have the same (simplified) procedure CreateCustomer which take parameters CustId, CustName and CustAddress.

Via this service host, I want to be able to accept requests that specify the following parameters: database filename, stored procedure to execute and the parameters to the procedure. I have no idea on how to send these parameters, but they could be:

- database=corpdb
- proc=createcustomer
- params=(CustId=DummyCorp,CustName=Dummy Corp
  International,CustAddress=Cloud 9)

The questions that keep me busy:
Is this a good or bad idea, and if it's a good one, how do I set it up?

How do I process the incoming requests? which format request should I use, and is there something simular to WCF's SOAP message to help me create proxy classes for the customers who want to build their own custom software using our webservices. How will they connect to this host in their software? and can I call the stored procedures from within the host directly?

I am sorry if this is (too) vague, but I am not very experienced in build webservers or webservices. If needed, I will clarify stuff. Thanks for reading.

Regards, Ted

Comment: Why do you even have to worry about the StoredProc? For an example if all you need is create a customer in a specific database, why not just create a `Customer` class and pass it on to a method called `CreateCustomer` in your web api controller? In your customer class you can have an enum to represent the database.

Comment: If possible I would like to keep any kind of definition of stored procedures or domain knowlegde out of my host. I just want it to pass the data to a adoconnection and try and execute the stored procedure. If it does not exist in the database the execution will fail and I will report back to the user. This way, if new stored procedures are introduced I do not have to change my webserver application.

Comment: So your intention is to create a system/tool to execute stored procs? Not really a business system? It is possible to do this. You need to have a `Class` where you can specify everything that you need to run a stored proc.

Comment: Correct. It should just execute stored procedures via webservices so that we don't have to give our *secret* dba passwords to customers, because they might end up corrupting the databases. One step further is to give customers a chance to have 3rd party organisations (via web, SSL certificates, etc) to submit data (like new products) directly in the database of the supplier that uses our application.

Comment: ok. :). I am worried about the level of security that you are going to implement in this tool though. Anyway, which part of the tool that you are struggling with?

Comment: To start with the global design... and how can I make it easy to use as an API for our customers?

Comment: This is a very broad question. I do not think anybody in this forum can help you with a detailed design. You need to study how wcf works first. Then you need to think about your front end, in my opinion, it will be a challenge since you have to build a lot of dynamic interfaces etc.

Comment: Thats exactly why I dont want to use wcf... but perhaps I can use webapi or restful services?